# Creating push and pop methods within a user defined LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Recently, my class has been studying ArrayLists and LinkedLists.  This past week we received an assignment that asked us to create push and pop methods within our LinkedList stack class.  I understand the logic behind stacks such that it's last-in-first-out, but I am having trouble with the actual code.  I am fairly new to computer science (this being my second course ever) and this particular assignment is literally causing me to pull my hair out.  I already turned this assignment in, but we have a midterm next week and I would like to do well on it.  I have been all over the web and my textbook looking for help, but nothing.  My professor only refers me to the TA and the TA is only concerned with helping me with the logic, not the actual code.  I'll post the instructions my professor gave me below, as well as my code so far.  Thanks in advance.

**From the professor:**

Implement stacks using the template given in the following Java 
files:

CS401StackInterface.java CS401StackLinkedListImpl.java

```
public interface CS401StackInterface<E>
{
   /**
    * Get the top element on the stack.
    * 
    * @return the first element on the stack.
    */
   public E pop();

   /**
    * Adds an element on the top of the stack.
    * 
    * @param e - The element to be added to the stack.
    */
   public void push(E e);

   /**
    * Determines the number of elements in this data structure.
    * 
    * @return the number of elements currently resident in this
    *         data structure.
    */
   public int size();
}
```

Here is the actual class where I attempt to define my methods:

```
public class CS401StackLinkedListImpl<E> implements CS401StackInterface<E> 
{
    private LinkEntry<E> head;
    private int num_elements;

    public CS401StackLinkedListImpl()
    {
        head = null;
        num_elements = 0;
    }

    public void setElement(LinkEntry<E> anElement){
        head = anElement;
    }

    /*Append the new element to the end of the list*/
    public void push(E e)
    {
        LinkEntry<E> temp = new LinkEntry<E>();
        temp.element = e;
        temp.next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    /*Remove the most recently pushed element at the end of the list*/
    public E pop()
    {
        head.next = head;
        num_elements--;
        return (E) head;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        LinkEntry<E> temp = new LinkEntry<E>();
        for (temp = head; head != null; head = head.next)
            num_elements++;
        return num_elements;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String string = "";
        LinkEntry<E> temp = new LinkEntry<E>();
        for (temp = head; temp != null; temp = temp.next)
        {
            string += temp.element.toString() + "";
        }
        return string;
    }

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Inner classes                                                      */
    protected class LinkEntry<E>
    {
        protected E element;
        protected LinkEntry<E> next;

        protected LinkEntry() { element = null; next = null; }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my main class where I test my methods:

```
import java.util.*;

public class App {

    public static <E> void main(String[] args) {

        CS401StackLinkedListImpl<String> my_stack = new CS401StackLinkedListImpl<String>();
        my_stack.push("Brian");
        my_stack.push("Chris");
        my_stack.push("Joe");
        System.out.println("Stack size: " + my_stack.size());
        my_stack.pop();
        System.out.println("Stack size: " + my_stack.size());
        my_stack.toString();
    }

}
```

When I run my main class this is what it returns:

```
Stack size: 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at week6.CS401StackLinkedListImpl.pop(CS401StackLinkedListImpl.java:30)
    at week6.App.main(App.java:66)
```

Everything I've come across just tells me to create a new Stack, which is easy because then I don't have to worry about the "innards" of the code, but that's not what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `NullPointerException` is on line 30, but you pasted your snippet without package or imports. Which line is line 30?

Comment: I would also recommend that you should use num_elements++ in your push method.  That way you always know how many elements are in your stack so your size method can just return num_elements and doesn't have to try to calculate it.

Comment: @user1723905.. Actually you are going great.. If this is your 2nd course..

Comment: Looks like you are doing pretty well. What development environment are you using? Whatever it is, I strongly suggest learning how to use whatever debugging tools you have available. This will let you look at the values of the variables in your code and help you track down where the problems are.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `size` method. It corrupts the value of `head` so that it is `null`. Then your call to `pop` gets an NPE.

You also have a problem with variable initialization - `num_elements` will just increase on every call to `size`. You can simplify this by increasing the variable on calls to `push`.

Also your `setElement` will corrupt your stack, if used, because it just sets `head`, without patching up the next pointers.

Sorry, I see that this is turned in homework... so here are some concrete ways to correct the code:

```
public CS401StackLinkedListImpl()
{
    head = null;
    num_elements = 0;
}

public void setElement(LinkEntry<E> anElement)
{
    if (head != null)
        anElement.next = head.next; //New top-of-stack needs to point to next element, if any
    else
        anElement.next = null;
    head = anElement;
}

/*Append the new element to the end of the list*/
public void push(E e)
{
    LinkEntry<E> temp = new LinkEntry<E>();
    temp.element = e;
    temp.next = head;
    head = temp;

    num_elements++; // Increase number of elements count here
}

/*Remove the most recently pushed element at the end of the list*/
public E pop()
{
    E result = head.element; // Save return value of TOS
    head = head.next; // Corrected POP action
    num_elements--;
    return result;
}

public int size()
{
    //Remove below since count is kept accurate with push/pop methods
    //LinkEntry<E> temp = new LinkEntry<E>();
    //for (temp = head; head != null; head = head.next)
    //    num_elements++;
    return num_elements;
}
```

You might want to add an addition check in `pop` to throw a better exception than NPE if there are no elements, such as:

```
if (head == null)
    throw new StackUnderflowException(); // and define a StackUnderflowException; or use a standard exception with a message
```

Comment: Actually, it's not actually homework, per se...it's originally based on homework, but he's handed in the assignment already.  This is just for learning.  Don't know if that would change your answer, but it seemed worth mentioning.

Comment: This answer is coming up nicely, so I've upvoted it. A few more things: don't forget to update num_elements in setElement(); also consider renaming this method to setHead() to be more specific; you may also reuse it in push(). All this if you still feel like it's worth keeping this method. I personally don't see its use.

Comment: @Zecc, actually `num_elements` shouldn't change in `setElement` (or `setHead`) since the size of the stack is not changed.

Comment: @KevinBrock thanks for the help!  This was my first time posting on this site and I wasn't expecting to receive help so quickly, I really appreciate it.  Granted I had already turned in my homework, but I feel much better about my exam coming up next week now.

Comment: `num_elements` definitely changes when `head == null`. It should become 1. `num_elements` should also increment by 1 when adding element `e` to the list. If element `e` was already there on the list, then there is possibly an element `e2` where `e2.next == e` and you should fix that (`e2.next = e.next`). Unless the intended semantics of setElement/setHead is removing the front element of the list; in which case `num_elements` also changes.

Comment: "Unless the intended semantics of setElement/setHead is removing the front element* **s** * of the list; in which case `num_elements` also changes."

Answer (score 0):

```
public void push(E e)
```

It seems ok.

```
public E pop()
```

It doensn't seem ok: you assign to the `head.next` element itself, this creates a loop. Then you return the actual `head`. You should first save current head somewhere, then update `head` reference to the next element and return the previous head.

```
public int size()
```

Method is wrong: first of all you instantiate a useless element to `temp` but you don't need it (since you will use the temp inside the loop and you should initialize it to the current `head`. Then check your for loop: you are using `head` either in the stop condition either in the end of loop iteration. You should never use `head`, since you are just iterating on the list and not modifying it, but just `temp` (check your `toString` code which appears to be correct).

Comment: And `size` doesn't initialize `num_elements` so it will just continue to increase. Really num_elements should be incremented in `push` and then `size` would then return the value.

Comment: Actually it's because `head` is used in `size` that they are getting the NPE since `head` is corrupted after that call.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason but my answer was more wide, just to let him do the correct thing and understand why.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code, it appears your Pop method is backwards.

In your push method, you assign the current *head* element to the 'next' attribute of the new LinkEntry, and then make that the new head.  Therefor, when you pop the item off the list, you need to assign the 'next' element back to the *head* of the list.  so your code, which is:

```
head.next = head;
```

should be:

```
LinkEntry<E> toReturn = head;
head = head.next;
return toReturn.element;
```

In effect, you are cloning the *head* reference to the current item at the top of the stack (so you can return it), then moving the *head* reference to point to the next item in the stack

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Append the new element to the end of the list*/
public void push(E e)
{
    LinkEntry<E> temp = new LinkEntry<E>();
    temp.element = e;
    temp.next = head;
    num_elements++;//Increment count<--- Correction
    head = temp;
}

/*Remove the most recently pushed element at the end of the list*/
public E pop()
{
    E returnValue =head.element ;<--- Correction
    head=head.next;<--- Correction
    num_elements--;//Decrement count
    return  returnValue;
}

public int size()
{
   return num_elements;<--- Correction
}
```

Comment: In `pop` it should be: returnValue = (E)head.element [or drop the cast since `element` is the same type]